# How to print a statement in a single line

Tags: python, printing, subprocess

I am unable to print an output statement in a single line from cli. The line breaks down into 3 lines. I tried printing it using print function and then tried print with a comma like `print "......",` and now I am using `format` style but none of them work.

Could anyone take a look at this please.

Below is my code :

```
self.length = len(self.src_mnt)

for copy in range(0, self.length):
    self.src_mnt[copy] = self.src_mnt[copy].replace('\/','/')
    self.tgt_mnt[copy] = self.tgt_mnt[copy].replace('\/','/')

    self.getSrcCount   = 'cd'+' '+self.src_mnt[copy]+';'+' '+'ls -l | wc -l'
    self.srcWord       = subprocess.Popen(self.getSrcCount, shell=True,
                                          stdout=subprocess.PIPE,)
    self.srcWc         = self.srcWord.communicate()[0]

    self.getTgtCount   = 'cd'+' '+self.tgt_mnt[copy]+';'+' '+'ls -l | wc -l'
    self.tgtWord       = subprocess.Popen(self.getTgtCount, shell=True,
                                          stdout=subprocess.PIPE,)
    self.tgtWc         = self.tgtWord.communicate()[0]

    if self.srcWc == self.tgtWc:
       self.srcMsg = "Copied: %s files out of %s from %s to %s" % (
            str(self.tgtWc), str(self.srcWc), self.src_mnt[copy], self.tgt_mnt[copy])
       print self.srcMsg
```

Below is my output:

[image: screenshot]

I need the output in a single line.

Answer (score 0):

The values `self.srcWc` and `self.tgtWc` are already strings, and appear to have `\n` newline characters at the end of each string.

You can get rid of the newline with the string `strip()` method, which will remove any leading or trailing whitespace. Try something like:

```
    self.srcWord          = subprocess.Popen(self.getSrcCount, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,)
    self.srcWc            = self.srcWord.communicate()[0].strip()
```

Comment: After adding strip() at the end of self.srcWc and self.tgtWc i got rid of that line break problem. Thanks for helping me, this problem looks very simple now but when i was writing such a huge code i could not figure out that \n is suffixed to that variable. I am a happy man now, thank you very much.

Comment: Then you should mark this answer as accepted so that this question no longer comes up as unresolved. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to remove all newlines before your print it out. e.g:

```
>>> s = 'Abc \n new-line'
>>> print 'Hi %s' % s
Hi Abc 
new-line
>>> s = s.replace('\n', '')
>>> print 'Hi %s' % s
Hi Abc  new-line
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally the tuple of output strings obtained via the `Popen.communicate()` method will each contain one or more lines ending with newline characters. A simple way to to break this up into a list of lines *and remove the newlines* is to use the string method [`splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines). To apply it to the `stdoutdata` captured in your example, change the indicated lines below in your code to the following:

```
    self.srcWc         = self.srcWord.communicate()[0].splitlines()[0]
```

and

```
    self.tgtWc         = self.tgtWord.communicate()[0].splitlines()[0]
```